# Looking for short story/novella I read in the early 1980s about people hibernating in winter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, psychology, novella

A man finds himself in a farming society. The people run out of food every winter and hibernate. The man has a hard time the first couple of years and wakes starving in the middle of winter. Eventually he adjusts and spends many years with these people. 
At the end of the story the man is rescued - he was actually in a car wreck and spent many days crawling in the wilderness. He perceived the nights as winter and the days as summer, and hallucinated the farming society.

Comment: Hmm... with it all being a hallucination, that might be out of our purview?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No, no. Well inside. If the twist would have been in a spoiler, would that have eased your mind?

Comment: @MrLister: I'll yield to your judgment on this one.